# Multiple models to load using multi-thread

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, threadpool

I have 180 SVM models to run concurrently.
Currently I load the models into an array at the start.
Then when I need to run the models, I use pthread to create 180 threads, 
then each thread acquires the pointer to each model, and does some calculation.

My concern is, creating 180 threads every time I want to do some calculation may create serious overhead(and there are a lot of calculations to do). 
So what I was thinking is, loading the SVM models into 180 threads at the start, and reusing them every time I want to do some calculation.

Is my idea at all feasible? Loading different models into each thread and using all the thread at the same time?
I thought about thread pooling, but I don't think this is a typical thread pool use case.
I would appreciate any kind of advice. Thanks.

Comment: Sure it's feasible - why not?  A while loop round your calcuation with some suitable signaling at the top should be fine.  If you can avoid continually creating/terminating/destroying 180 threads, great!  Not sure about the thread pool issue - 180 threads is fine if any of them make blocking calls, but if they're CPU-intensive, you may want to try a task/pool solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! My task is actually CPU-intensive so I did some test with "threadpool.sourceforge.net".
But the performance was not any better than using pthread. 
I guess since boost::thread is a wrapper of pthread, there can't be any "great" improvement performance-wise. 
I am planning to test OpenMP now. If that doesn't work out, I might as well just stick with pthread.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really run them concurrently, unless you have 180 CPUs to play with.  Otherwise, you're wasting a lot of energy switching between threads while they fight each other to make forward progress.

A better approach might be to create a number of threads close to the number of CPUs or cores you have available, and distribute the individual models to the threads from a queue.

Suppose you have 8 cores you wish to use for this.  Create 8 "worker" threads, have each one pick one off the queue of 180 and work on it.  When any worker thread finishes, it does whatever it would do with the results in the 180 thread scenario above, and grab the next SVM model off of the queue.  Have this continue until all 180 models are processed.

It will probably take less wall clock time to complete and almost definitely put less resource load on the system than the 180 threads at once.  Once you have this set up, you can experiment with the number of worker threads you run to determine a sweet spot for the pool size.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!! I actually have tried that out with the thread pooling scheme mentioned above. I was using a Xeon 12-core machine, so naturally 12 "worker" threads was giving me the best result. Then I tried using OpenMP and got a slightly better result than 12 "worker" thread scheme(reducing the wall clock time from 256 to 249 sec.). I guess OpenMP is the way to go since it is easier to implement.